# Create file with reference to a file filtered based on common information from other file in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 text files. file1 has 6 columns and 2 rows but file2 has 2 columns and 5 rows like these examples:

file1:

```
Code        S1      S2      S3      S4      S5     
X2019060656_12      4.068522        1889.299282     1547.771971     434.392935      4346.019078
X2019060657_05      1.318325        1290.142988     285.579601      73.329331       2222.198520
```

file2:

```
Class       group
X2019060656_12      A
X2019060657_05      A
X2019060658_04      A
X2019060659_03      A
X2019060660_08      A
```

I would like to make a subset of file2 filtered based on the intersection of the column "Class" of file2 and the column "Code" in file1.

This is the expected output:

```
Class       group
X2019060656_12      A
X2019060657_05      A
```

To do so, I made the following code in python:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

file1 = {}
keys1 = []
values1 = []
with open("file1.txt") as file1:
    for line in file1.lines():
        keys1.append(line[0])
        values1.append(line[1])
        dict_file1 = dict(zip(keys1, values1))


file2 = {}
keys2 = []
values2 = []
with open("file2.txt") as file2:
    for line in file2.lines():
        keys2.append(line[0])
        values2.append(line[1])
        dict_file2 = dict(zip(keys2, values2))
        newlist = [] 
        for item in dict_file1:
            for item2 in dict_file2:
                if item1 == item2:
                    new_list.append(line)

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in new_list:
        f.write("%s\n" % i)
```

but the output file is not like the expected output. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I am not an expert in python, but I wonder why variables file1 and file2 are redefined like `file1 = {}` and `file2 = {}` in following lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `pandas` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.txt",delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.txt",delim_whitespace=True)
df2[df2['Class'].isin(df1['Code'])]
```

Output:

```
    Class   group
0   X2019060656_12  A
1   X2019060657_05  A
```

If you want to export to file, use `df2.to_csv`